# PHP: How do I read a .txt file from FTP server into a variable?

Tags: php, ftp

I have two servers. I already have a .txt file in the one I'm connecting to.

I need to get the .txt file contents and put them into a `$` variable. Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
$ftp_server = $_POST["site"];
$path = $_POST["path"];
$ftp_user_name = $_POST["username"];
$ftp_user_pass = $_POST["pass"];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

$remote_filename =
    "/" . $_POST["path"] . "/" . "#" . $result["id"]
    . " - " .    $result["LastName"] . ", " . $result["FirstName"]
    . "/" . $_POST["title"] . ".txt";
ftp_get($conn_id, $content, $remote_filename, FTP_ASCII);
```

This code connects to the FTP and I used the `ftp_get` to copy from one text file to a variable called `$content`. I know a variable doesn't belong in this parameter, but I'm sold right now. I have no idea how to read this .txt file.

Is there a way to do this with the PHP FTP functions?

Now, when I try this:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents('ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file');
```

It gives an error:

> Warning: fopen(ftp://...@goldenbooklet.com/101Notebook Backup: 22-08-2013/#11 - Cappucci, Ryan/queen.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: FTP server reports 550 /101Notebook Backup: 22-08-2013/: not a regular file in /home/content/34/11614434/html/adminpdo.php on line 269

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks again

Answer (score 20):

The [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is the easiest solution:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file');
```

If it does not work, it's probably because you do not have [URL wrappers enabled in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

---

If you need greater control over the reading (transfer mode, passive mode, offset, reading limit, etc), use the [`ftp_fget`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php) with a handle to the [`php://temp` (or the `php://memory`) stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.memory):

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('hostname');

ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$h = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');

ftp_fget($conn_id, $h, '/path/to/file', FTP_BINARY, 0);

$fstats = fstat($h);
fseek($h, 0);
$contents = fread($h, $fstats['size']); 

fclose($h);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

*(add error handling)*

Comment: Correct Answer!

Answer (score 12):

If you've already opened a connection via ftp_connect, this would probably be the best answer:

```
ob_start();
$result = ftp_get($conn_id, "php://output", $file, FTP_BINARY);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this, this code is from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

```
<?
$filename = "ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

echo $contents;
?>
```

If error, please change the file permission to 777 or 775. Hope this may help.

Comment: I still get an error when I try that. I posted the error above.

Comment: The code above is work fine with ordinary .txt file. Is it possible that the file you going to read is not a file (according from your link, it's look like you're trying to read a folder) or may be it's .php or .aspx file? If so you can not get that .php file.

Comment: Yes it is a txt file, but for some reason no matter what I try I still get the error.

Comment: please read this article >> http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WS-20000817-DM02.htm it's about error 550. May be it's not coding problem.

Comment: You're getting this error because you're trying to read from a stream, and reading stops when a packet is available.  Note that data streams are sent in packets.  To do this, you need the following:

`<?
$filename = "ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

echo $contents;
?>`