# FTP Files are not accessible using fopen or file_exists or file_get_contents

Tags: php, ftp, fopen, file-exists

I am trying ftp connections for **file read**.

All I want to do is

- read particular ftp dir
- list all its text files
- and read them one by one

I am successful in listing files in given directory.

For eg: below code returns `$emailfiles` array with `TEST.txt` as one value.

But when I try to open/read the same file content using  `fopen/file_get_contents` , it is giving the error: **" Failed to open Stream "**

I am able to access a file from another ftp : **.38**, which is public ftp.
The ftp I want to actually use is **.94**, for which I have full privileges, as I am able to access files from browser with same link. I'm also able to write/paste files from windows explorer.

But **I am unable to read the same file from php code**.

Below is my code for ftp connection and testing.

```
    $ftp_server = "10.96.5.94";
$ftp_serverpath = "ftp://".$ftp_server;
$ftp_user_name = "myusername";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypassword";
$email_dir = "ebill";
try {
$con = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if (false === $con) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
}

$loggedIn = ftp_login($con,  $ftp_user_name,  $ftp_user_pass);
if (true === $loggedIn) {
    echo 'Success!';
} else {
    throw new Exception('Unable to log in');
}

ftp_pasv($con, true);
$emailfiles = ftp_nlist($con, $email_dir);
print_r($emailfiles);


//$filename = "ftp://10.16.0.38/ebill/TEST.txt";
$filename = "ftp://10.96.5.94/ebill/TEST.txt";
$pr = file_exists($filename);
// OR
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How do I read a .txt file from FTP server into a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392321/php-how-do-i-read-a-txt-file-from-ftp-server-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, This solved my error.

```
$filename = "ftp://username:pa‌​ssword@hostname/path/to/file";
```

Thanks.

Comment: hello, above code works fine, but what if we want to download from "ftps" and with port number , I used it like this 
'ftps://username:ssword@ftps.hostname.com:2222/path/';

but it gives me error like : Warning: fopen(): connect() failed:

can you please help me about this?