# Read contents of every file in FTP directory using one connection

Tags: php, ftp

My goal is to connect to an FTP account, read the files in a particular folder, grab the content and list out to my screen.

This is what I have:

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect('HOST_ADDRESS');

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

if (!$login_result)
{
    exit();
}

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "DirectoryName");

$files = [];

foreach ($contents AS $content)
{
    $ignoreArray = ['.','..'];
    if ( ! in_array( $content , $ignoreArray) )
    {
        $files[] = $content;
    }
}
```

The above works well to get the file names I need to grab the content from. Next I want to recurse through the filename array and store the content into a variable for further processing.

I am not sure how to do this, I would imagine it would need to be something like this though:

```
foreach ($files AS $file )
{
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($conn_id, filesize($file));
    $content[$file] = $contents;
}
```

The above idea comes from here:
[PHP: How do I read a .txt file from FTP server into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392321/php-how-do-i-read-a-txt-file-from-ftp-server-into-a-variable?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Although I don't like the idea of having to connect each time to grab the file contents, would prefer to do it on the initial instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to connect/login for every file, use the [`ftp_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) and reuse your connection ID (`$conn_id`):

```
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    // Full path to a remote file
    $remote_path = "DirectoryName/$file";
    // Path to a temporary local copy of the remote file
    $temp_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "ftp");
    // Temporarily download the file
    ftp_get($conn_id, $temp_path, $remote_path, FTP_BINARY);
    // Read the contents of temporary copy
    $contents = file_get_contents($temp_path);
    $content[$file] = $contents;
    // Discard the temporary copy
    unlink($temp_path);
}
```

*(You should add some error checking.)*

Comment: ok - thank you. So if I wanted to keep the file I would just not use: unlink?

Comment: Sure, but in that case you probably want to use a more meaningful file and path like `$temp_path = "/path/".$file`. And the `$temp_path` variable name would be confusing too.