# Accessing file from FTP (failed to open stream: operation failed)

Tags: php, ftp

I've been trying to solve this but can't find the solution, I am trying to get the contents of file from my FTP server via PHP.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.testftp.co.uk");
$ftpuser="myusername";
$ftppassword="mypassword";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpuser, $ftppassword);

if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
echo "FTP connection has failed!";
exit;
} else {
echo "Connected To FTP";
echo  nl2br ("\n");
}

$data = file_get_contents('ftp://myusername:mypassword@ftp.testftp.co.uk/test.tsv');
```

I get can connected to the FTP ok but can't read the file, I get the error "failed to open stream: operation failed", im not sure what I am doing wrong, any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: file permissions?

Comment: folder and file are set to 0700

Comment: You establish the connection with the ftp extension and then do the actual download with stream wrappers. As a general rule, you can't mix different extensions to do one same thing.

Comment: Ahh I see, ok so if I use ftp_get I can save the .tsv file locally but i really wanted to just read the contents of the file from the FTP server without copying locally first, is that not possible? Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505825/850848

Comment: file_get_contents does not work for me, i have checked the wrapper in php.ini and thats ok, I am using XAMPP would that be causing problems perhaps?