# How to read the CSV file of the FTP Server?

Tags: php, symfony4

I have a filename `test.csv` at my FTP Server. I am working on reading this file and import to the table.

So far I created a class as follows:

```
class FtpHelpers {
    protected $ftpOpen;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ftpHost = 'www.abc.com';

        $this->ftpUsername = 'username';
        $this->ftpPassword = 'password';

        if (is_null($this->ftpHost)) {
            throw new Exception("FTP references are missing or incomplete.");
        }

        if (is_null($this->ftpUsername) || is_null($this->ftpPassword)) {
            throw new Exception("FTP credentials are missing or incomplete.");
        }

        $this->ftpConnection = ftp_connect($this->ftpHost);

        if($this->ftpConnection === false) {
            throw new Exception("Could not connect to the FTP server.");
        }

        $loginResults = ftp_login($this->ftpConnection, $this->ftpUsername, $this->ftpPassword);

        if ($loginResults === false ) {
            throw new \Exception("The credentials were refused by the FTP server.");
        }

        ftp_pasv($this->ftpConnection, true);
    }

public function getDataList($targetFolder)
{
    $this->ftpOpen = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    ftp_fget($this->ftpConnection, $this->ftpOpen, $targetFolder, FTP_BINARY, 0);

    $ftpStat = fstat($this->ftpOpen);
    fseek($this->ftpOpen, 0);
    return fread($this->ftpOpen, $ftpStat['size']);
}
}
```

This class I inject to other class where I need to import. When I try to print `$this->ftpHelpers` in other controllers, I get connection result.

My question is what next I should do to read this `test` file.

Comment: file_get_contents() might be simpler. This answer has examples of that and ftp_connect(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505825/3103434

Comment: `file_get_contents` didn't worked for some reason So instead I used fopen('php://temp', 'r+');... as in the SO. Now I have issue with how to read the CSV records. I will update what I did

Comment: What is the error you're getting?