# How to load png data from ftp server without downloading it?

Tags: php, ftp, png

I have png photos uploaded to the ftp server. I want to see these photos directly on my local website. I don't want to download photos to the local. I want to have only ftp as the source itself.

I want to create a loop on the local website where my photos will alternate. The source of this loop will be the ftp server.

I don't know how to do it without downloading data. Is it even possible? Thanks

I connected to ftp with this command:

```
 <?php 
$host =  "xxx" ;
$user  =  'xxx' ;
$password  =  'xxx' ;
$ftpConn  =  ftp_connect ( $host ) or die("Nepodařilo se připojit k $host");;
$login  =  ftp_login ( $ftpConn , $user , $password ) ;

if(ftp_login ( $ftpConn , $user , $password )){
  echo "Přihlášení k FTP proběhlo v pořádku!";
}
else{
  echo "Přihlášení k FTP neproběhlo v pořádku!";
}

ftp_pasv($ftpConn, true);

// get file list of current directory
$file_list = ftp_nlist($ftpConn, ".");
var_dump($file_list);

// close connection
ftp_close($ftpConn);

?>
```

The connection was successful. The data were also located here.

Comment: See [Retrieve image from FTP to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17169251/850848).

Comment: This proposal is not bad. I just have more png files. I can't have a new php script for every slide.

Comment: Of course not. You pass the name to the script in URL query string – Like here: [List and download clicked file from FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52855025/850848).

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a complete beginner in php. I can't understand it. 

This is my php file:
 `<?php

header('Content-Type: image/png');

echo file_get_contents('ftp://aladin.mysteria.cz:xxx@aladin.mysteria.cz/mesic/1/teplota.png');

?>`

And in html i call  `<img src="ftp-load.php" />` 

How exactly can I add another image to php?
And how do I call in html ? 
Thank you.

Comment: `<img src="ftp-load.php?filename=teplota.png" />` => `echo file_get_contents('ftp://aladin.mysteria.cz:xxx@aladin.mysteria.cz/mesic/1/'.$_GET["filename"]);`