# FTP file download with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to make a download button on my webpage, using FTP.
But when I try to do this, the downloaded file is saved onto the machine which hosts my website, and not the users PC, which I want. Isn't it possible to make it, so the file can be downloaded as normal from the FTP like in the image below?

[image]

This is the download FTP function I have right now, which downloads the file into my websites project folder..

```php
function FTP_download($id){
    ob_end_flush();
    $remote_file = $id.'.log';
    $local_file = $id.'.log';

    $conn_id = ftp_connect($this->ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $this->ftp_user_name, $this->ftp_user_pass);

    // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem\n";
    }

    // close the connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);
}
```

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php. That isn't FTP though. You can't change the protocol the request was made over.

Comment: @user3783243 Aaah I see, so I have to make a download `.php` file and include some specific `headers` and then use the `readfile` function to create the download? :)

Comment: You don't need a separate file necessarily, but yes you need to make PHP forward the file on to the client

Comment: @ADyson Just tried the `readfile` and it outputs the content of my `text file`, so I guess I do have to make some kind of another file with some download `headers?`

Comment: You can put the header calls in this file. That tells the browser what to do. Natively you are saying it is HTML so the browser renders it as such.

Comment: @user3783243 yeah then I need another `ftp_download.php` file, in my case :) since the file I use right now, contains some webpage stuff. In other words have a `webpage.php` and a `ftp_download.php` file

Comment: You have basically asked this already and we have already pointed you to [Retrieve image from FTP to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17169251/850848). There's no difference between implementing a download/display link to an image or to any other file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes but no, because i tried to do it like that but didn't know I had to change some things :) I've written a solution now for this problem

Answer (score 0):

So I've made a solution for download my `.log` files

**FTP_download.php**

```php
...
$file = $_GET['file'].'.log';
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get the size of $file
$size = ftp_size($conn_id, $file);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
readfile('ftp://'.$ftp_user_name.':'.urlencode($ftp_user_pass).'@'.$ftp_server.'/'.$file);
exit;
```

and I have a function with a download link to this `.php` page

```php
<?php
function FTP_download($id){
    ?> <a href="ftp_download.php?file=<?php echo $id; ?>" download> Download logfile</a> <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Once you have logged in anyway, using `ftp://` is inefficient, as you unnecessarily create another connection, use `ftp_get($conn_id, "php://output", $file, FTP_BINARY);` as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/47240635/850848

Comment: Should I just remove the connect/login part then?